# How to make an existing frame responsive in Openedge,progress 4gl

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I've an old desktop application developed in progress 4gl.There is a frame contained in a progress window now my task is to make the frame responsive ie based on the size of its container window the frame should resize dynamically.Is it possible in Progress any workaround will be appreciated.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Once the frame has been "realized" you cannot change its height or width.

Prior to that you can manipulate the geometry via the frame handle.

To change things after the frame has been displayed you will basically need to build a new frame to replace the old one.

Comment: I think you mean once the ***window*** has been realized. In our application we're resizing frames all the time. You can also resize windows if they are made resizable.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you don't own the source code. If your window hasn't been set as RESIZE, then there's really no luck.

Otherwise, I created this simple program, which should make it possible to manipulate the window and the frame inside it. Now remember: All fields will have to be manually repositioned inside the frame. You also might want to set session:suppress-warnings to YES before you get this running, because every time a widget doesn't fit the frame, OpenEdge will let you know about it. You might need to cycle all objects inside the frame's field-group, to make it happen. And remember to get fill-ins side-label-handle to move them too, otherwise the fill-in itself moves, but the text stays. It's a lot of work.
So without further ado, the code:

```
DEFINE VARIABLE hProgram AS HANDLE      NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE hWindow AS HANDLE      NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE hFrame AS HANDLE      NO-UNDO.
run <ProgramNameGoesHere> persistent set hProgram.
run enable_UI in hProgram.
assign hWindow = hProgram:current-window
       hFrame  = hWindow:first-child.

/* Resize Variables */
DEFINE VARIABLE dWinXC AS DECIMAL     NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE dWinYC AS DECIMAL     NO-UNDO.
/* /Resize Variables */

ON WINDOW-RESIZED OF hWindow 
DO:
  /* Defining a minimum size here */
  if hWindow:width-chars  < 74 or 
     hWindow:HEIGHT-CHARS < 22 then return no-apply.

  run piResize.
END.

procedure piResize:
def var dXC    AS DECIMAL NO-UNDO.
def var dYC    AS DECIMAL NO-UNDO.

/**--------------------------------- Screen Size ----------------------------**/
assign dXC                        = dWinXC - hWindow:width-chars
       dYC                        = dWinYC - hWindow:height-chars
       dWinXC                     = hWindow:width-chars
       dWinYC                     = hWindow:HEIGHT-CHARS
/**-------------------------- Objects on Screen -----------------------------**/
       hFrame:width  = hWindow  :WIDTH
       hFrame:height = hWindow  :HEIGHT no-error.
/**-------------------------------- Frame Sizes -----------------------------**/
     ASSIGN hFrame:width  = hWindow:width
            hFrame:height = hWindow:HEIGHT no-error.

end procedure.

wait-for 'close' of hProgram.
```

Now, I don't know if this does you any good, since you can't probably interfere with behavior at will. Notice the inclusion of a trigger overrides whatever was there before (since your window did not resize, I don't think it will harm it. But doing that for a widget that already has an event procedure will cause it to stop doing what it currently does (unless you can code it, but again I don't think you have the code).
I apologize for the code not being just the genius patch that Stack Overflow loves so much, but it's a complex issue. Hope it helps.

Oh, and this was made using Progress 10.2B. I imagine if your code is previous to v8, you might be out of luck.